# What is the best practice for logic inside a constructor? (Java)

Tags: java

I am learning Java and one of the resources I am using is Coursera. For one of the assignments, I am writing a constructor for a CaesarCipher class where I am initializing the alphabet and the "shifted" alphabet.

```
public CaesarCipher(int key) {
    this.alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    this.shifted = alphabet.substring(key) + alphabet.substring(0, key);
}
```

The idea is that when you give the "key" in the constructor it will shift the alphabet accordingly. One possible issue I noticed is that if the key is longer then the alphabet string then you will get an index out of bounds error. To prevent this I would assume we could write logic inside the constructor as such:

```
public CaesarCipher(int key) {
    while(key > 26) {
        key = key - 26;
    }
    this.alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    this.shifted = alphabet.substring(key) + alphabet.substring(0, key);
}
```

Having a bit of knowledge on Java before taking this course though I know you typically wouldn't include logic inside a constructor. For a case like this what is best practice?

Comment: And what if `key` is negative? Your constructor is `public` which means any class can use it and pass whatever int it wants to `CaesarCipher`. You've got to check quite a few things on that `key` hence better to make a method.

Comment: Hi Mark! A simpler way to "normalize" the key would be to use [Math.floorMod(int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-), like this:`key = Math.floorMod(key, 26);`. This is kind of like saying `key = key % 26` except it also handles negative keys.

Comment: It's completely appropriate to validate and/or normalize input parameters is a constructor,  or to perform one-time setup work. Whether that setup code is in a separate private method called by the constructor, or inline in the constructor itself, is up to you.

Comment: @dnault Maybe it is "completely appropriate to validate and/or normalize input parameters in a constructor" but it's not what I've seen working with dozens of other Java developers and writing/reading thousands of lines of Java for well over a decade.  Pretty much all I've seen in working production code is "dumb" initialization constructors.

Comment: Incidentally, since indexes are zero-based, the maximum key is 25. Mininum key is zero, max key is 25, giving you 26 possible keys.

Comment: @ZackMacomber You are correct, there are other scenarios that I am probably not considering but this is an introductory class for Java so even this scenario I'm checking for is much more than what the course is asking me to do. This was the most obvious check I could think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, you shouldn't have any logic in the constructor except validation. So for your example:

```
public CaesarCipher(int key) {
    if(key < 0){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("key < 0");
    }
    key%=26;//Replaces the while loop
    this.alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    this.shifted = alphabet.substring(key) + alphabet.substring(0, key);
}
```

The advantage of this method is, that it [fails fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) and doesn't show an error somewhere later. See this example:

```
public class Foo{
   private String bar;
   public Foo(String s){
      this.bar = s;
   }

   public int getLengthOfBar(){
       return this.bar.length();
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
      String s=getStringFromSomewhere();//May return null
      Foo f=new Foo(s);
      ...Some code....
      int len = f.getLengthOfBar(); //BOOM, if s is null, it will fail with a NullPointer Exception.
      ...Do something with len....
   }
}
```

If you would add a check in the constructor, you would see really fast, that you shouldn't pass `null`.
Yes, you could add a check to `getLengthOfBar`, too, but I really think, that you should validate in the constructor. (At least for small, checks like Nullchecks, ranges,...)

Comment: Nice answer :-) May I offer a suggestion? If a key greater that 26 is valid, why couldn't a negative key be valid? `key = Math.floorMod(key, 26);`

Comment: Awsome! I just tried out your approach in an online environment and this works the way I am intending. I never used the %= operator and it seems useful.

Comment: @dnault Thank you, I was thinking, that for example a shift of 72 is fixable, as it "rolls over", while a negative shift is ambiguous, for example -1: Should you make it equals a shift of one or 25?

Comment: Your recommendation of `IllegalArgumentException` is exactly the right thing to do. However, if there's one-time setup of something that _will_ be needed, like `shifted`, there's no harm in doing that in the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just accept the `key` in your constructor (it's good practice to make it immutable by making it a `private final int`) and then make https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle methods to do something with that `key`.

Also `alphabet` could be a `public static final String`

`shifted` looks like it should be a method to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would implement it.

```
public class CaesarCipher {
    private int key;
    private String alphabet;

    public CaesarCipher(int key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    }

    public String shift(){
        int key = getKey();
        return alphabet.substring(key) + alphabet.substring(0, key);
    }

    public int getKey(){
        return  key % 26;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaesarCipher cc = new CaesarCipher(31);
        System.out.println(cc.shift());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Based on above comment/answer, validation for the key can be done something like

```
    public int getKey(){
        if(key<0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key < 0");
        }
        return  key % 26;
    }
```

Comment: This will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `key` is negative

Comment: @ZackMacomber I have edited my answer. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If you're going to use separate `shift` and `getKet` methods to initialize these values, you might as well make these methods private and call them once in the constructor. Otherwise you're cluttering your public interface, and potentially repeating a lot of initialization work every time you want to decode something with the cipher.